# Onsubmit on a form not working the first time and behaving oddly on all subsequent tries

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick, overlay, onsubmit

I currently have a problem with a "onsubmit" call on my form.

The goal is to use a iframe in an overlay to update another iframe behind that overlay.

Whenever I try to update the "background" iframe using a button ("onclick") and this code:

```
parent.document.getElementById('frame_login').src=parent.document.getElementById('frame_login').src;
```

It works everytime.

But if I try to do it on the form "onsubmit":

It does not work the first time (the "background" iframe is not updated) but it does work the second time, although, the refresh will give the result it was supposed to on the first time. Here is an example:

- I open the overlay and I login, the overlay displays that I am logged in but the "background" iframe does not change.
- I click logout on the overlay, the overlay displays that I am logged out, the "background" iframe shows that I am logged in.
- I login again using the overlay, the overlay will say that I am logged in, but the "background" iframe will now say that I am logged out.

I am aware that the "onsubmit" code is not exactly executed the same way that an "onclick" is, but I was unable to find a solution thus far, is there any way to fix this behavior please? Perhaps a different approach?

Here is the code of the "background" iframe:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><iframe src="user.php" width="100%" height="70px" frameborder="0" id="frame_login" name="frame_login"></iframe>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the code of the overlay iframe:

```
<?
include('config.php')
?>

<script>
function myFunction() {
parent.document.getElementById('frame_login').src=parent.document.getElementById('frame_login').src;
}
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<? 
if($user->data['is_registered'])
{
    //User is already logged in to phpBB

?>
  <form method="post" action="phpBB_logout.php" onSubmit="return myFunction()"/>
    <table width="75%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height:25px;"/>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">Welcome</td>
        <td align="center"><? echo $user->data['username'] ?></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Logout"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <?    
}
else
{
?>
  <form method="post" action="phpBB_login.php" onSubmit="return myFunction()"/>
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="height:25px;">
      <tr>
        <td align="center">Username:
          <input type="text" size="20" name="username" /></td>
        <td align="center">Password:
          <input type="password" size="20" name="password" /></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <?
}
?>

<input type="button" size="30" name="button" onClick="myFunction()" value="Button"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Please note that "onclick" on the form does the same behavior as the "onsubmit" (I tried to set the "onclick" on the submit input on the form: `<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="myFunction()"/>`.

Thank you for your time and help, it's greatly appreciated.